# Delete some simulators from xCode

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to remove some simulators with old iOS version (8.0-8.3 for example) from xCode? I'm using a MacBook Air with only 120 Gb disk for development and extra 10-15 Gb can be very useful for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Goto

1. Xcode > Windows > Devices. You will see list of simulators.

[image]

2. Right click on any, chose Delete.

[image]